# might collapse vs. could collapse

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

a. I didn't want to cross the bridge because it could collapse under my weight. They forced me to cross it and it didn't collapse.

b. I didn't want to cross the bridge because it might collapse under my weight. They forced me to cross it and it didn't collapse.

Are both of the above grammatically correct and meaningful?

I am pretty sure (a) is fine, but not entirely sure. I have stronger doubts about (b).

Answer (score 1):

Either is possible. It might be more natural to say *in case it collapsed* or *for fear that it would collapse.*